# error: cannot find symbol method BindView(MainActivity)

Tags: android, butterknife

I used butterknife in my app by adding classpaths for it, annotation processor and plugin. Then I replaced all occurrences of `Bind`, in the java files, with
`BindView`.
Now I'm getting the error `Error:(81, 20) error: cannot find symbol method BindView(MainActivity)`.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Share your full crash report from logcat and also post your dependency version of this library.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to add **Butterknife.bind(this)** in onCreate() method of the activity. Like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.lbl_title)
TextView lblTitle;

@BindView(R.id.input_name)
EditText inputName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // bind the view using butterknife
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_enter)
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have entered: " + inputName.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

You are required to add **multiDexEnabled true** in your build.gradle(app) in the defaultConfig section. Like this:

```
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

This may help you to resolve the issue you mentioned in comment.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Done that. This resolved that error. Now I'm getting this error. : 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: @Corroded please try the edited answer to resolve your issue.

Comment: Rakshit, that line already exists in the defaultConfig of app level gradle.

Comment: @Corroded You can try this: File -> Invalidate caches/restart and click invalidate and restart. then after the studio restarts go to: Build -> Clean project.

Comment: Resolved that error by replacing 'compile' in gradle file with 'implementation'.
Now I'm getting this error:

"could not find com.jakewharton:butterknife-implementation:8.5.1"

Comment: @Corroded can you please post your build.gradle (app) and build.gradle(module) So I can help you to resolve your issue easily.